# Christmas word: I am in France, without I

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Find out this Christmas word with this clue:

> I am in France, without I.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is

> JESUS, because it's "je suis" (the French translation for "I am"), without the letter I.

Comment: It sould have been 'in french' instead if 'in france'

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=k7LcX5PGAePI_QaNu6eIDg&q=I+am+in+France&oq=I+am+in+France&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQyQMyAggAMgIIADIICAAQFhAKEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMggIABAWEAoQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoFCAAQsAM6CAgAELEDELADOgcIABCwAxAKOgUILhCwA1CBlwRYgZcEYKeiBGgBcAB4AIABoQGIAaEBkgEDMC4xmAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCsABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjT28-e1dftAhVjZN8KHY3dCeEQ4dUDCAw&uact=5

Comment: @Abdur-RahmaanJanhangeer: But that is a part of the riddle, besides they speak French in France. So it's still an accurate statement. As in, if you are **in France**, how would you say "I am"?

Comment: @musefan I was referring to the fact that maybe the author misstyped in the title. Coming from Mauritius, we speak french, that's why the question caught my attention!

Comment: @entioneveryone Google interpretes your input, it's not necessarily how you would put it.

Answer (score 12):

Simple:

> Noel

I misread

> the capital I as a lowercase l, so there is No El. A *very* Christmas word in France.

Comment: Brilliant, I love this answer - so good on many levels